# How to get magento customer session logout time

Tags: magento, session

I want to create an app , which brings a pop-up when the customer session is about to expire.
So for this purpose I will be requiring customer session value .
Please help .
Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You cant check session remaining time. Because whenever you access the system session will be automatically refreshed. You can check only that session is available or expire. And There is no php function to get it. But We can do it by ajax. For example your session expire time is 30min. Set ajax for every page get refreshed and calculate that time with minus the 30min. And show your pop up message at what time (remaining time ) you want..!!

Comment: Hi Nikhil..You need to use Ajax functions for your applications. As I mentioned above here is the one nice example. I guess this one what exactly you were looking..http://pure-essence.net/2010/02/14/jquery-session-timeout-countdown/   and here is the explanation http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3858120/alert-user-if-session-is-going-to-expire-option-to-renew-session